# Express-session is not persistent on NGINX reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, express, session, nginx, passport.js

I want users to be able to log in with Discord and save their this to a session with `express-session`. When I run the frontend and backend locally it works great, but when I deploy it to my Digitalocean server with NGINX the session does not persist. The client never receives the cookie needed for the session to persist.

This is the setup for the session login using `express-session`, `passport` and MySQL to store the session.

```
import express, { Request, NextFunction, Response } from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import session, { SessionOptions } from 'express-session';
import DiscordStrategy from 'passport-discord';
import passport from 'passport';
import mysqlSession from 'express-mysql-session';
import secretConfig from 'config/secret';
import discordConfig from 'config/discord';
import apiConfig from 'config/apiconfig';
import { RESPONSE_CODE } from './helpers';

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const app = express();

if (isProd) {
  app.set('trust proxy', 1); // Trust first proxy
  app.disable('x-powered-by'); // Hide information about the server
}

// Enable CORS
app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    const sameServer = !origin;

    if (sameServer || apiConfig.CORSWhitelist.includes(origin)) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
    }
  },
}));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new DiscordStrategy(
  {
    clientID: secretConfig.discord.publicKey,
    clientSecret: secretConfig.discord.privateKey,
    callbackURL: discordConfig.callbackUrl,
    scope: discordConfig.scopes,
  },
  (accessToken, refreshToken, user, done) => {
    process.nextTick(() => {
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

const MysqlStore = mysqlSession(session);
const mysqlCfg = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  user: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'database',
};

const sessionCfg: SessionOptions = {
  secret: secretConfig.sessionSecret,
  name: 'plan-b-auth',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  proxy: isProd,
  cookie: {
    secure: isProd,
  },
  store: new MysqlStore(mysqlCfg),
};

app.use(session(sessionCfg));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const checkAuth = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();

  res.status(RESPONSE_CODE.UNAUTHORIZED).json('Unauthorized');
};

app.get(
  '/discord/auth',
  passport.authenticate('discord', { scope: discordConfig.scopes }),
);

app.get(
  '/discord/auth/callback',
  passport.authenticate('discord', { failureRedirect: apiConfig.websiteDomain }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(apiConfig.websiteDomain);
  }
);

app.get(
  '/discord/auth/logout',
  (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
  }
);

app.get(
  '/discord/auth/me',
  checkAuth,
  (req, res) => {
    res.json(req.user);
  }
);

app.listen(apiConfig.port, (err) => {
  if (err) return console.info(err);
  console.info('Listening at http://localhost:8080/');
});
```

On the frontend (using Next.js) I fetch the user data with this fetch

```
fetch('https://myapi.com/discord/auth/me', {
    headers: {
      cookie: req.headers.cookie,
    },
    credentials: 'include',
  })
```

This is my server block for the api (and client, they are similar)

```
server {
        server_name myapi.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3002;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_redirect off;

                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
}
```

Again: when I run the code local and sign in, it works. When I deploy it to my Digitalocean server, it no longer works. There is no cookie stored on the client on the deployed website, but there is a cookie present when I run it local. Sessions are stored in my MySQL database when deployed, however.

Comment: Do you have a production `mysqlCfg` as well? As I only see pointing it to localhost. Also, what are your server logs showing? Is the application running without errors?

Comment: @eenagy No, the `mysqlCfg` is also used on production. The config works fine on production. There are no errors when running any of the code. The entire authentication process works fine, up until fetching user data. This will produce a 401 because the cookie with the sessionID is never saved on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Next.js is a server-side rendered application. You won't have access to the request headers from the browser.

So your question is about how to set cookies for Next.js.

You must use `next-cookies` for accessing it.

See the examples directory for [cookie-auth](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-cookie-auth)

You must implement cookie-auth example for accessing cookie on both the client and server.
The following helper functions stores and retrieves the cookies for authenticated users:

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import Router from 'next/router'
import nextCookie from 'next-cookies'
import cookie from 'js-cookie'

export const login = async ({ token }) => {
  cookie.set('token', token, { expires: 1 })
  Router.push('/profile')
}

export const logout = () => {
  cookie.remove('token')
  // to support logging out from all windows
  window.localStorage.setItem('logout', Date.now())
  Router.push('/login')
}

// Gets the display name of a JSX component for dev tools
const getDisplayName = Component =>
  Component.displayName || Component.name || 'Component'

export const withAuthSync = WrappedComponent =>
  class extends Component {
    static displayName = `withAuthSync(${getDisplayName(WrappedComponent)})`

    static async getInitialProps (ctx) {
      const token = auth(ctx)

      const componentProps =
        WrappedComponent.getInitialProps &&
        (await WrappedComponent.getInitialProps(ctx))

      return { ...componentProps, token }
    }

    constructor (props) {
      super(props)

      this.syncLogout = this.syncLogout.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount () {
      window.addEventListener('storage', this.syncLogout)
    }

    componentWillUnmount () {
      window.removeEventListener('storage', this.syncLogout)
      window.localStorage.removeItem('logout')
    }

    syncLogout (event) {
      if (event.key === 'logout') {
        console.log('logged out from storage!')
        Router.push('/login')
      }
    }

    render () {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }

export const auth = ctx => {
  const { token } = nextCookie(ctx)

  /*
   * This happens on server only, ctx.req is available means it's being
   * rendered on server. If we are on server and token is not available,
   * means user is not logged in.
   */
  if (ctx.req && !token) {
    ctx.res.writeHead(302, { Location: '/login' })
    ctx.res.end()
    return
  }

  // We already checked for server. This should only happen on client.
  if (!token) {
    Router.push('/login')
  }

  return token
}
```

You must wrap your page `withAuthSync` and use the cookie for accessing authenticated data.

```
class YourPage extends Component {
...
}
YourPage.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
  const { token } = nextCookie(ctx)
  const url = `${process.env.API_URL}/discord/auth/me.js`

  const redirectOnError = () =>
    typeof window !== 'undefined'
      ? Router.push('/login')
      : ctx.res.writeHead(302, { Location: '/login' }).end()

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        cookie: token
      }
    })

    if (response.ok) {
      return await response.json()
    }

    return redirectOnError()
  } catch (error) {
    // Implementation or Network error
    return redirectOnError()
  }
}
export default withAuthSync(YourPage)
```

Also you must call `login` and `logout` functions after successfully authenticating through discord API. See the working examples in the github examples folder, posted above.